# SQL query from VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When I use below code I get desired output:

```
mQuery = "Select FileName, Filetype from CredoReports where "
mQuery = mQuery & " FileName = '" & mSearchTag & "'"
mQuery = mQuery & " or FileName like '" & mSearchTag & "%'"
mQuery = mQuery & " order by FileName ASC"
```

Query received by SQL DB Trace is

```
SELECT "FileName" ,"FileType"  FROM "dbo"."CredoReports" WHERE ((("FileName" = 'L-R5' )  OR ("FileName" LIKE 'L-R5%' ) ) ORDER BY "dbo"."CredoReports"."FileName"
```

When I use below code i do not get any output.

```
mQuery = "Select FileName, Filetype from CredoReports where "
mQuery = mQuery & " FileName = '" & mSearchTag & "'"
mQuery = mQuery & " or FileName like '" & mSearchTag & "[^0-9]%'"
mQuery = mQuery & " order by FileName ASC"
```

Query received by SQL Trace is

```
SELECT "FileName" ,"FileType"  FROM "dbo"."CredoReports"
```

Here when I use `[^0-9]`, `WHERE` clause is missing in SQL DB trace.

Extra info: `Set oRecordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mQuery)`

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using?  The only database that recognizes `[^0-9]` as meaning "no digit" for `like` is SQL Server (and Sybase).

In MySQL, you would use `regexp`:

```
mQuery = mQuery & " or FileName regexp '^" & mSearchTag & "[^0-9].*$'"
```

Comment: or `rlike` - Synonym for regexp

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2014. Query generated by VB is : Select FileName, Filetype from CredoReports where  FileName = 'L-R5' or FileName regexp '^L-R5[^0-9].*$' order by FileName ASC ... It did not return any output. Also when directly running in MS SQL Management Studio it returns error which is <<An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'regexp'>>.

Comment: It seems issues is with ^ and [] symbols as they have specific meaning in VB and while interpreting this query these symbols are not being treated as String. And hence SQL DB is not receiving full query. Not sure.

Comment: After using suggested query SQL Trace received same query. SELECT "FileName" ,"FileType"  FROM "dbo"."CredoReports". No output.

Comment: Just now used <<mQuery = mQuery & " or FileName like '" & mSearchTag & Chr(91) & "^0123456789" & Chr(93) & "%'">> still no luck. It looks like [] are creating some issue at run time.

Comment: Query traced by SQL DB is <<SELECT "FileName" ,"FileType"  FROM "dbo"."CredoReports">> Where clause missing and no data returned.